# SQLAlchemy postgresql.ARRAY size

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to add size of the postgres array in SQLAlchemy?

Like SQL type Integer[2]:

```python
column = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Integer), size=2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you just define the column as ARRAY of some base type, like `integer[]`. You can include dimensions in the type declaration, like `integer[3][3]`, but they are without effect, as they are not enforced. I quote the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size
>   limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified
>   length.